# App store is only showing non-curated apps

Tags: appcenter

I am having an issue with the app store where I am only able to see non-curated apps. I am not able to see the pay what you want apps. For example, if I search "Planner" this is what I get:

[image]

I have tried reinstalling the app center a few times and rebooting but nothing is helping. How do I fix this?

Comment: What output do you get running sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade?

Comment: It looks like the Calendar app is not listed under Non-Curated apps. It's listed above it.

Comment: If possible, can you check if the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list exists on your system? If so, what are the contents of that file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like planner is not only a Non curated app but it is free (no payment option)[image: planner] if you click on the icon there is an option for an Appcenter app and non curated (flathub) version of the app
[image: planer options]

I recomend you to click on the icon and see do you have an AppCenter option available also

Answer (score 0):

Is this on elementary OS 6 (Odin)? According to https://builds.elementary.io/ it looks like this is still a known issue.